# How can I indicate to Eclipse where my runtime libraries are?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, runtime

I downloaded JavaFX SDK which contains some jar files in lib, and some dll files in bin.
I included only the jar files in Eclipse so there is no compile problem, but when I run the project I get "JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application".
How can I include the dll files for the javaFX SDK too in Eclipse.

Note : I tried to use e(fx)clipse as an alternative to this but it doesnt work for me, so I'm trying to install javaFX manually.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included your new JDK in `Preferences -> Java -> Installed JRE` ?
If yes, then in `Debug Configuration : yourProject -> JRE` use *Alternate JRE* that JDK